Coarse well-distributedness/equidistribution of Pell sequence prefixes
I am interested in the distributedness or "mixing" behavior of certain
linear recurrences modulo powers of $2$.
In particular, consider the Pell sequence (https://oeis.org/A000129),
modulo $2^k$ for a sufficiently large integer $k$,
defined as
\begin{align*}
    a_0 &\equiv 0,\\
    a_1 &\equiv 1,\\
    a_{n} &\equiv 2 a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \pmod{2^k}.
\end{align*}
I want to know how well-distributed this sequence is in a coarse sense:
the sequence should be
$< 2^{k-1}$ half the time
and $\ge 2^{k-1}$ half the time.
In other words, the most significant bit of the sequence
should be equally likely to be $0$ or $1$.
I can show that this is true on a long time scale,
on the order of $2^k$:

The period of the Pell sequence mod $2^k$
is exactly $2^k$, which can be shown using the sequence's binomial identity and arguing about the factors of each term.
Then with the same techniques, we can show $a_{n} \equiv a_{2^{k-1}+n} + 2^{k-1}$.

Thus, the second half of a period of the sequence
is equal to the first half but with the most significant bit toggled,
and hence exactly half of the period is $<2^{k-1}$.
However, I want to show that this mixing happens on
short time scales as well.
We know that there is an explicit Binet formula
for this sequence (e.g. on OEIS) which
shows that the $n$th element of the sequence grows exponentially in $n$,
and so we expect the first $\Theta(k)$ elements
of the sequence to stay below $2^{k-1}$.
However, from computer-generated examples
I've observed that if we ignore
the first $\Theta(k)$ elements
to allow the sequence to "mix",
then
the cumulative fraction of subsequent large
sequence elements
always stays above an absolute constant (say, $0.1$), and
rapidly converges to $1/2$.
Is this true for all sufficiently large $k$?
That is, is there some absolute constant $C$ such that for
all $N > Ck$
the following holds?
$$\frac{\#\{Ck<
n\le N : a_n\in [0,2^{k-2}) \}}{N-Ck}< 0.9.$$
(Here, I would be happy with $2^{k-2}$
or any $\Omega(2^k)$
as the threshold for "large" instead of $2^{k-1}$; since $a_n$ grows like $2.414^n$, choosing a smaller cutoff eliminates the possibility that for some choices of $k$ the sequence wraps back around modulo $2^k$ before it becomes large.)

Aren't the sequences you're considering $2^k$-automatic? In which case you can use the full toolbox of automatic sequences and constant-length substitutions to understand letter-frequencies, discrepancies, and mixing properties. However, those results tend to deal with long term behaviour, whereas it looks like you're considering slightly more local behaviour, so I'm not sure if this is quite what you need.
